# Checkbox Autopost back won't work in DataList

Tags: c#, asp.net, autopostback

I'm trying to operate a function when Checkbox is checked (via AutoPostBack), for some reason, it does not work and OnChecked function won't happen.

Here's my code:

```
<table class="table table-hover task-table">
    <asp:DataList ID="ListOfTasks" runat="server" RepeatLayout="Flow" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" ClientIDMode="Static">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 20px;">
                        <asp:Label runat="server" Visible="false" ID="TaskIdVal" Text='<%# Eval("TaskId") %>'></asp:Label>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="DoneCb" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnInit="OnChecked" ClientIDMode="Static"/>
                </td>
                <td><%# Eval("Name") %></td>
                <td><%# Eval("UserId").ToString() != Session["userid"].ToString() ? GlobalFunctions.ParagraphEvalHtml("<i class='glyphicon glyphicon-share'></i> &nbsp;", (Eval("FirstName") + " " + Eval("LastName")), "") : string.Empty %></td>
                <td><span class="text-left text-sm-2  pull-left"><%# Eval("DueDate") == null ? string.Empty :  GlobalFunctions.ParagraphEvalHtml("<i class='glyphicon glyphicon-time'></i>&nbsp;", Eval("DueDate").ToString(), "") %></span></td>
                <td>
                    <asp:LinkButton runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-sm btn-danger pull-left" Text="<i class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash' style='color:#fff;'></i>" /></td>
            </tr>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:DataList>
</table>
```

This is the codebehind (.cs):

```
protected void OnChecked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (DataListItem dli in ListOfTasks.Items)
    {
        CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)dli.FindControl("DoneCb");
        Label lbl = (Label)dli.FindControl("TaskIdVal");
        if (chk.Checked)
        {
            GlobalFunctions.DoneTask(lbl.Text);
        }
    }
}
```

And finally, here's the function:

```
public static void DoneTask(object TaskId)
{
    db.update("UPDATE Tasks SET Done = 1, DoneDate = '" 
                  + DateTime.Now + "' WHERE Id = '"+TaskId+"'");
}
```

I would highly appreciate your help :-)